# How can the picture be taken behind the ''top pick'' text?

Tags: html, jquery, css

How can the picture be taken behind the ''top pick'' text?

The problem: https://iili.io/VQKa0F.jpg

Page which has the problem: https://awet123.blogspot.com/2022/04/testing-all-required-boxes-for-niche.html

Comment: Try modifying the z-index of the "text"

Comment: Please add the code so that we can reproduce your problem. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong place of `.cg-our-top-pick`. You should replace it to position after `.cg-li-photo`

Bad:

```
<div class="cg-layout-img">
    <div class="cg-our-top-pick">TOP PICK</div>
    <div class="cg-li-photo">
        <a class="cg-aff-link" href="https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01M12RE4A?tag=kitlit-20&amp;linkCode=ogi&amp;th=1&amp;psc=1" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">
            <img alt="Goxawee Cordless Drill Screwdriver" class="cg-img-1" src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/413Spl-3a0L.jpg" loading="lazy" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="cg-li-ratebadge">
        <div class="cg-rate"><span>9.4/10</span> <span>Our Score</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Good:

```
<div class="cg-layout-img">
    <div class="cg-li-photo">
        <a class="cg-aff-link" href="https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01M12RE4A?tag=kitlit-20&amp;linkCode=ogi&amp;th=1&amp;psc=1" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">
            <img alt="Goxawee Cordless Drill Screwdriver" class="cg-img-1" src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/413Spl-3a0L.jpg" loading="lazy" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="cg-our-top-pick">TOP PICK</div>
    <div class="cg-li-ratebadge">
        <div class="cg-rate"><span>9.4/10</span> <span>Our Score</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]